# Angular: while using native JS Sort() getting compatible signature error

Tags: angular, typescript

According to [Type Compatilibilty in TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) obj x is assignable to y if they share the same property (name for example in the article)

I'm trying to sort out an array in Angular that has several objects with a particular prop that is of type number.

example:

```
const arr = [
0: {num: 5},
1: {num: 1},
2: {num: 3},
3: {num: 10}
]
```

when trying to sort object above i'm getting below error;

**Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((compareFn?: (a: any, b: any) => number) => any[])**

What am I missing about comparing the same values inside an object?

edit:

```
 this.returnData = data((a,b) => {
          return a.num - b.num;
        });
```

this function is defined in my ngOnIt, returnData is an array type defined outside ngOnit() in the class, data is an array coming in from my services

Comment: please, paste the code where you are trying to sort the `arr`

Comment: done, look at the edit. Thank ya

Comment: @Generaldeep, I supouse your array is const arr = [{num: 5},{num: 1},{num: 3},{num: 10}]  I don't know why you put 0:..,1:...

Comment: each object is at an array index, what i wrote is correct.